# How to access private IP addresses with WAN running on 5GHz band of router

Tags: networking, router, routing, port-forwarding, wan

I have an access question regarding my special setup. Hoping you can help as I've reached the end of my networking knowledge and am going in circles now. Here's the background to my setup -

I am piggy-backing on an xfinity hotspot so I can have my own network in my apartment garage(garage is a building over from my apartment, so my network can't reach). I have security cameras wired to the router, and can access them externally using an iPhone app with P2P setup. However, I can't access them via web browser as I can't find the correct route. Looking to see how I can access them externally. Here is how I have my router configured -

**5GHz Radio (eth2) -**

- Wireless Mode: Wireless Client
- Interface: WAN
- SSID: xfinity

**2.4GHz Radio (eth1) -**

- Wireless Mode: Access Point
- Interface: LAN
- SSID: myPrivateNet

**LAN -**

- Router IP: 192.168.1.1/24
- DHCP Enabled
- Camera IP: 192.168.1.17 (Trying to access externally)

**WAN -**

- IP Address: 172.20.20.20
- Gateway: 172.20.20.1
- DHCP Enabled
- Public IP: 73.91.225.xx

I have tried a number of port forwarding rules from 73.91.225.xx to 172.20.20.x to 192.168.1.x, but can't crack it. If I am on the network, I can access the router admin page via 172.20.20.20:8080, but no access from the public IP address.

Any thoughts on what routing rules I need?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see what `Xfinity hotspot` is here, neither the public IP nor the hotspot is *owned* by you (not even "ephemerally"), which means you were trying to port forward just on your own router, which in turn makes no sense in this case. So no, it won't work. You'll need to do it by some other means (e.g. some VPN server that actually allows you to port forward).

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks for your feedback. I will look into the VPN solution. One other question- Forgive my ignorance, but how does the iOS app know where to look/how to access the camera externally but I can't through my own means?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those cameras, but as far as I know, they connects to some server and register/expose the current public IP and port they are using at the moment, so your phone/app can can find it via the server. I don't know the details of the model/protocol, like whether it is (always) really "P2P" for at least the video transmission part. (I guess ultimately it depends on the vendor.)

Comment: Probably something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching#Flow